# "I cannot seem to find it"

Tags: word-usage

In a programming site, someone just wrote:

> I cannot seem to get them both to find their relevant objects.

It seems I've heard something similar before, say:

> I cannot seem to find it.

With my simple-minded mind, I would think that what they really mean is:

> It seems I cannot find it.

... because what they really want is not to **seem** to find X but really **find** it.

My question is: is it common to say "I can't seem to do it" when one really means "It seems I can't do it", and is it "correct" (in whatever sense that makes sense)?

[edit]
There is another question on [how to use 'seem' in negative form](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46723/how-to-use-of-the-word-seem-in-negative-form); however, my interest is a bit different. I would like to know how native English speakers perceive the "I can't seem..." expression: for example, if someone is looking for something for quite some time, would they rather say (1) "I can't seem to find it" or (2) "It seems I can't find it"? Would (1) seem (even slightly) illogical or is it just a natural way to say it?

Comment: But the real question is, what is a *'simple-minded mind'*? :O

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use of the word "seem" in negative form](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/46723/how-to-use-of-the-word-seem-in-negative-form)

Comment: `Varun KN`, by "simple-minded mind" I meant someone like me, who can more or less understand some English but does not have the intuitions of a native speaker :P (but of course, on re-reading, it sounds like infinite recursion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is: is it common to say "I can't seem to do it" when one
>   really means "It seems I can't do it", and is it "correct" (in
>   whatever sense that makes sense)?

Yes, it's common, and the difference is that the first expresses a certain level of frustration, as in, "I've looked everywhere and I can't seem to find it."

The second construction would express a certain level of resignation, "It seems I can't find it, so we'll have to do without it."

The two can also be used interchangeably when the level of either frustration or resignation is low.

Comment: I am accepting this answer as the most instructive [for the asker, at the moment]. The other answers and comments were useful as well. Several comments as well as Colin Fine's answer pointed to the concept of [raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_%28linguistics%29).  FumbleFingers mentioned _distancing_ of of the speaker from what is said. TRomano completely exposed the _naïveté_ of the OP's approach to parsing. Thank you all! :)

Answer (score 2):

With "simple-minded mind", I understand the OP to be saying that he is parsing the sentence rather like a first-generation robot, like this:

I cannot {seem to find it}.

Does not compute.

But "seem to find" there is a nice bit of *deixis*, which only a HAL would pick up on.

`cannot {seem to {find}}` is an inline-aside which here could be paraphrased as "cannot find although I am and have been searching".

Comment: Thanks! But `cannot {seem to {find}}` is simplified to `cannot{seem to find}` which evaluates to `not-making-sense` :(  The problem is to find how a native speaker transforms `!CAN(seem(find(x))` to `seem(!CAN(find(x))`  because  in my mental system `seem` cannot be nested in `CAN`. (Where `!` is shorthand for `NOT`).

Comment: maybe "I seem not-being-able-to-find-it" is a middle step?

Comment: "seem" there is like a /* comment */  in code in a future-generation programming language that supports not only instructions but metadata revealing the intention and mental state of the programmer.

Comment: **seem** can be a lexical expression of repetition/recurrence/iteration.    *She tried to run into him "by accident" on campus for a few weeks after being introduced to him at the party, but she never **seemed to be** in the right place at the right time.*

Comment: @lebatsnok Raising is quite common in English. It's a bit like you want to say "I seem to cannot find it" but that would be ungrammatical so you "raise" it and end up saying "I cannot seem to find it" instead. This is, as far as I can tell, pretty much automatic among fluent speakers. A simpler case is the preference for "I don't think she understands it" over "I think she doesn't understand it" (though both alternatives are grammatical in this case). This is, again, automatic, AFAICT.

Comment: "i can't seem to find it" can also be parsed as `!MAYBE(seem(find(x)))` if CAN is used here to indicate possibility rather than ability. In that interpretation, it doesn't mean "it seems I cannot find it" but rather "it cannot be that it seems that I will find it" which indeed adds a degree of frustration.

Answer (score 2):

*Seem* is a "[raising to subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_%28linguistics%29)" verb.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems I cannot find it.

I'm emphasizing the situation here, implying that the circumstances or situation is causing my inability, not me.

> I cannot seem to find it.

I'm emphasizing myself here, implying that it's my fault I can't find it, not the circumstances or situation.