# meaning of "I can’t seem to..."?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is an example from [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hang_2#hang_2__34):

> I can’t seem to get the hang of this game.

As you may know, 'get the hang of something' means **to understand something**. But I don't understand the meaning of 'I can't seem to...' here.

Comment: *This seems easy* = *this **appears** to be easy* (from the speaker's point of view). Correspondingly in your example, the speaker ***has the impression*** that he's unable to get the hang of the game (he doesn't understand it, or can't play it properly). You might think it's odd for the speaker to include those extra two words (since they ***seem to*** be completely superfluous), but that's just how native speakers often talk. It's a kind of "hedge" (weakening the assertion, perhaps inviting someone else to say *Of course you can! It's easy! Look - I'll show you!*).

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers. Can we rephrase that as "It seems to me that I can't get the hang of this game"? Or is its meaning somewhat different?

Comment: Arham - the version in your comment is rather "unlikely", but it's hard to explain exactly ***why***. It would be perfectly natural to say, for example, *It seems to me that **you** don't understand what **I'm** saying*, but reversing the situation to *It seems to me that **I** don't understand what **you're** saying* is more than a bit "weird" (if I'm the speaker, I should at least know whether I do understand or I don't; it would be "unusual" for me not to even know *that* much! :)

Comment: ...note that per my first comment, *It seems to me [that] X is true* is a "weakened, hedged" way of saying *I **think** (but don't **know**) X is true*. That's to say I'm not ***sure*** - it's just that what I know and what I've seen gives me the *feeling* that X is true. But I might be wrong, and this form of words is often used when you're *expecting/inviting" the other person to "correct" what you think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["I cannot seem to find it"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93073/i-cannot-seem-to-find-it) On that one the OP seems to understand the "general" usage of ***it seems** [that X is true]*, but the OP here should find plenty of relevant information there (both in *answers* and in [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93073/i-cannot-seem-to-find-it#comment180973_93073).

Comment: Bearing in mind the usual equation between "can" and "be able to" (which is intuitive to native speakers, who effortlessly switch to forms of "be able to" when "can" doesn't possess the required nonfinite forms), I think we can posit a correspondence between "I *can't* seem to do it" and "I *don't* seem *to be able to* do it".  I can see, though, how a learner might expect "I can't seem" to mean "I'm not able to seem", which isn't quite the case in practice.

Answer (score 0):

can’t/couldn’t seem to do something

It is used to say that you have tried to do something but cannot do it,according to longman dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

From American Heritage Dictionary 4th Ed.

The expression ***cannot (or can't) seem to*** has occasionally been criticized as illogical, and so it is. *Brian can't seem to get angry* does not mean “*Brian is incapable of appearing to get angry*,” as its syntax would seem to dictate; rather, it means “*Brian appears to be unable to get angry*.” But the idiom serves a useful purpose, since the syntax of English does not allow a logical equivalent like *Brian seems to cannot get angry*; and the ***cannot seem to*** construction is so widely used that it would be pedantic to object to it.